# Calculating CSGO item float values from items with reduced float value spectre

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm playing around with some trade-up contracts to learn the system before I invest in a serious trade up. I'm trying to calculate the recieved float value in an excel cheet when all items have reduced float value spectre.

I bought 10x cheap `MAC 10 | Ultraviolet`'s with the following float values:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0.15418683 | 0.37252599 | 0.45620725 | 0.33419874 | 0.27844283 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0.37971455 | 0.25109288 | 0.37596929 | 0.19480962 | 0.31378764 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That results in an average of `~0.31109356`.

The MAC 10's has a min float of `0.06` and a max float of `0.8` giving them a float field of `0.74`.

And from the trade contract i got an `PP Bizon | Blue Streak` with float `0.29020962`.

The PP Bizon has the same min/max and float field as the MAC 10's, and in my logic that would mean that the average float value of the MAC 10's would equal the float value of the PP Bizon, but it does not.

If I take the average float value from the MAC 10's and multiply it with the float field, then add the float minimum it does add up (giving the fact that im only using 8 desimal points):

```
( AVG * FIELD ) + MIN = ( 0.31109356 * 0.74 ) + 0.06 = 0.29020936
```

Now my question is this, is the min/max values on the 10 trade-up items irrelevant making every item with high MIN absolutly worthless in a trade-up contract?

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR:* 
The actual Min-Max float range of the traded weapons isn't what matters, it's the actual float value of the individual weapons that determines the new weapons float.

I find it makes more sense if you work backwards.

First the weapon that you'll be getting needs to be determined. This is based on the collections that the weapons you put into the trade come from. In this example you're using all Mil-Spec grade weapons from the eSports 2014 Summer Collection. That means you'll randomly get one of the 5 Restricted grade weapons from that case (`Crimson Web Deagle`, `Steel Disruption Glock`, `Ocean Foam MP7`, `Virus P90`, or `Blue Streak PP-Bizon`).

Once the weapon is picked, it's float value is calculated based on the float of your traded in items:

```
(New Weapon's Max Float - New Weapon's Min Float) * Average Float of All Trades + New Weapon's Min Float = New Weapon's Float
```

In this instance the PP-Bizon is the new weapon so we can plug it's values in:

`(0.80 - 0.06) * 0.31109356 + 0.06 = 0.2902092344~`
([floating point values can get funky in computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point))

If the new weapon that was created was the Steel Disruption Glock (which has a different float range) the calculation would've been:

`(0.20 - 0.00) * 0.31109356 + 0.00 = 0.062218712~`

So, to answer your question: **The Min (or Max) float value itself doesn't affect the float of the weapon you receive. It's the actual float value of the individual weapons that determines the new weapons float**.

That being said, weapons with a better (lower) Min float value have intrinsic value in that they offer the opportunity of a weapon to have a better float value.

---

Lets look at receiving a `Corticera AWP` by trading up 10 `Steel Disruption Glocks` vs 10 `Blue Streak PP-Bizon`, both sets with an average float that falls at the median of their float ranges.

The new weapon has a float range of `0.30 - 0.06` so the calculation now looks like this:
`(0.30 - 0.06) * (Avg of Trade-Ins)  + 0.06`

The Glocks have a float range of `0.20 - 0.00`, so collectively their average float is `0.1`.
10 at that float will produce a Corticera AWP with a float of `0.084`
`(0.30 - 0.06) * 0.1 + 0.06 = 0.084`

The PP-Bizon have a float range of `0.80 - 0.06`, so collectively their average float is `0.43`.
10 at that float will produce a Corticera AWP with a float of `0.1632`
`(0.30 - 0.06) * 0.43 + 0.06 = 0.1632`

So, a collection of average Steel Disruption Glocks will produce a Corticera AWP with a better (lower) float value then a collection of average Blue Streak PP-Bizon.

[Source](https://youtu.be/1I-hwnrEMKA)